# design pattern: refactor the code like these

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, refactoring

I plan to to refactor my code below

```
1.Class A_Builder to build A_Model

Class A_Builder{
public A_Model build(arg1){
//build A_Model
}
}


2.Class B_Builder to build B_Model

Class B_Builder{
public B_Model build(arg2,arg3){
//build B_Model
}
}

3.Class C_Builder to build C_Model
Class C_Builder{
public C_Model build(arg4){
//build C_Model
}
}

4.Class D_Builder...
```

One builder to build a model,so I plan to use command pattern to refactor them,make build method as a command,but how to handle the different variable number like A is (arg1) and B is (arg2,arg3)

or any idea to refactor the code like these?thanks in advance.

Comment: the args in method are different

Comment: Do you want a single Builder that builds multiple models based on input, or do you want to refactor common code in your builders into a super class?

Comment: All models have different number of arguments in build functions, or it is possible to have build(..) in two builder classes with the same signature? Are model classes somehow related (have the same superclass etc)?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler:since they are doing analogous thing but building defferent type of Model,so I think could we refactor them?

Comment: @dbf: I want to put a supperclass for them,but looks not easy to create a supperclass for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the language you're using, but most languages that I've come across support the [overloading of functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

This means that you can declare two separate functions with the same name, but take different arguments, and then the language will examine the parameters you are passing when you make the function call and execute the appropriate function:

```
class Builder {
    public build( arg ) {
        // Build A Model
    }

    public build( arg, arg ) {
        // Build B Model
    }

    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if your function arguments are all of the same variable type, you could simply create a single function that accepts an array of parameters. An array can be of variable length, and so your single function could perform different actions, depending on the length of the array:

```
class Builder {
    public build( arg[] ) {
        switch( arg.length ) {
            case 1:
                // Build A Model
                break;
            case 2:
                // Build B Model
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the args in method are different

Comment: @simon.liu: Does this solution not work for you? Here also the overloaded methods have different number of arguments, as you have mentioned. Is it possible that 2 `build()` method of different `Builder` classes have same signature?

Comment: @Jamie: thanks guys,but I think overloading is not a good idea since they are doing defferent things(one build A_Model,another build B_Model,etc.). Using an array of parameters also not good since the C_Builder also has 2 args,and maybe D_Builder has only 1 arg.

Comment: @simon.liu If they're building different models, why do you want to consolidate the classes? If you have common code, create an abstract super class or create a class that can be used in each builder.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler:I think consolidate them could easy to maintain and help to extension